# Angular component not getting data from service to pass to shared control

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've set up a basic app that calls a service to get data to pass to a shared control by calling a service that exposes an observable.  However, the service is returning an empty array.  I'm am trying to figure out what the data is not being returned.

Here is a full stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o5wjvf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `combineLatest` needs to be subscribed to... otherwise your current call will not set the next value of `userItemsEntityListSubject$`

your current code:

```
  combineLatest(this.userItems$, this.items$).pipe(
      map(([useritems, items]) => {
        console.log(' inside the dataService combineLatest: ', useritems);
        return items
          .filter((i) => !useritems.includes(i.itemId))
          .map((item) => {
            return {
              entityId: item.itemId,
              entityName: item.itemName,
              entityCategory: '',
            };
          });
      })
    ),
      tap((val) => console.log(' the value of moSelectParticipants$: ', val));
    tap((val: IMySelectEntity[]) => this.userItemsEntityListSubject$.next(val));
```

not sure why you left the `tap` out of the `pipe`, maybe was a bad C&P

this is the fix (please also notice the square brackets in the `combineLatest`):

```
combineLatest([this.userItems$, this.items$]).pipe(
      map(([useritems, items]) => {
        console.log(' inside the dataService combineLatest: ', useritems);
        return items
          .filter((i) => !useritems.includes(i.itemId))
          .map((item) => {
            return {
              entityId: item.itemId,
              entityName: item.itemName,
              entityCategory: '',
            };
          });
      }),
    ).subscribe(items => this.userItemsEntityListSubject$.next(items))
```

Comment: Got it. The pipe was just misplaced. Adding the subscribed as you mentioned fixed the issue.  And I'm guessing it is the httpService calls for `items$`, `useritems$` that triggers that subscribe in the combine latest?  Why don't I need to add a `.subscribe` for the two observables that this one depends on?

Comment: The view does an implicit subscribe because you are using the var `mySelectEntities$` in the view and in your commented out code you have `this.mySelectEntities$ = combineLatest ...`

Comment: Ok. And lastly I see that I get an array of two objects that have the properties I want to bind to my list.  Why aren't they in the form: Observable<IMySelectEntity[]>?  Why is nothing being displayed?

Comment: do you mind sharing a link to your edited code?

Comment: Actually never mind.  I was missing one more call to get the list to populate.  Everything is working now. Thanks.